# How to Titanium with handle push notification?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, titanium

I use **caffeina GCM with Titanium**.I want to **convert** get push **notification object to JSON object**. How can I do?

I want to make dynamic.

Thanks

var req = require('it.caffeina.gcm').registerForPushNotifications({

```
    senderId : '480608162759',

    success : function(e) {
        console.log(e.deviceToken);


    },
    error : function(err) {
        Ti.API.error('Notifications: Retrieve device token failed', err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean this?

```
require('it.caffeina.gcm').registerForPushNotifications({

  senderId : 'YOUR_SENDER_ID',

  success : function(e) {
      console.log('deviceToken', e.deviceToken);
  },
  error : function(err) {
      console.error('Notifications: Retrieve device token failed', err);
  },
  callback: function(e) {

    var payload = null;
    try {
      // push payload is inside e.data
      payload = JSON.parse(e.data);
    } catch(ex) {
      console.error('error reading push payload', ex);
    }

    // if(payload) do whatever you want with payload ....

  }
});
```